# Relationship through one model

Tags: laravel

I have three tables - users, properties, devices.

```
users
 id
 name

properties
 id
 name
 user_id

devices
 id
 name
 property_id
```

How to define straight relationship to user model from devices model?

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->....();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to define such relation? Thanks.

Comment: Does chaining your relations fits for you? If you put in your user() function inside device model `$this->properties->hasOne('App\User');`

Comment: I tried to chain, but it doesn't return correct user.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set all relation in other classes.

```
class Property extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', null, null, 'property');
    }
}
```

You can provide a relation with in 4th parameter of belongsTo method.

Comment: I have tried hasOneThrough myself, but could not make it to work. I get this SQL error. `Unknown column 'properties.device_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `properties`.`device_id` as `laravel_through_key` from `users` inner join `properties` on `properties`.`id` = `users`.`property_id` where `properties`.`device_id` = 1 limit 1`

Comment: Updated version returns an object of the user, but it is not the correct one. It returns user by id of the property_id not of the actual user_id.

Comment: Ahh you're right. Since you would have to get property anyways in order to access to user, your only option would be to call $device->property->user to get the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //user model
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
   //role model
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
    //employee model
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    //value show using tinker command in command promote
     App\User::find(1)->employee;
     App\User::find(1)->role;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution, this is what I end up with.

```
class Device extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        $instance = new User();
        $instance->setTable('properties');
        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        return (new BelongsTo($query, $this, 'property_id', $instance->getKeyName(), 'property'))
                    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'properties.user_id')
                    ->select(DB::raw('users.*')
            );
    }
}
```

Hope this will be of help for somebody.